# How to set minimal window size to kivy application?

Tags: python, kivy

I try to set a minimum width and height to my kivy app.
I want it resizable with min size restriction.

In the kivy doc I read about `WindowBase` class which has parameters `minimum_height` & `minimum_width`.

WindowBase description: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html

How can I set the min size restriction to the basic window which `App` class creates automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the Window object:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.minimum_height = 400
Window.minimum_width = 400


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text="Hello World")


if __name__ in ("__android__", "__main__"):
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Just be sure to set both Window.minimum_width and Window.minimum_height -- if you only set one it will be ignored.